# SQL: Windows function

Tags: sql-server

I'm stuck with a new problem
I have two tables:

```
BudgetNumber   Name    Remaing(h)   EndDate

BU145122       Jhon       5       2018/11/15

BU145123       Jhon       20      2018/12/01

BU145124       Lewis      10      2018/11/15

BU145125       Lewis      50      2018/12/15
```

Actuals:

```
Actuals(h) Name       DATE

5          Jhon    2018/11/01

6          Jhon    2018/11/10

5          Jhon    2018/11/25

5          Lewis   2018/12/10
```

So in my final table, I'd like something like:

```
Name   Remaining(h)      Date      Budget

Jhon      5       2018/11/01     BU145122       

Jhon      14      2018/11/01     BU145123       

Jhon      9       2018/11/25     BU145123       

Lewis     45      2018/12/10     BU145125
```

So if the date of my budget is lower than my actual date, my budget is lost
If it's not the case, I substract my Actuals from my remaing(Table B)
I can get a table with a windows table but I'm stuck with the date
Is there another way to do that than a loop?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your data seems to have many typos, both in the character and numeric data.  Can you fix them?

Comment: When you say, "my budget is lost", do you mean the result is discarded?

Comment: Yes I can change it, it's not the data I have but this is an idea of what I'm trying to do

Comment: I don't understand what your desired logic here. What does does `remaining` represent? It seems that it represents a integer value, however, it's suffixed with a `'h'`, making "maths" against it impossible. For example, for Lewis' final value for `Remaining` the expression is `50-5`, but with your data that becomes `'50h' - '5h'` (as you can't subtract a `varchar` from a `varchar`), which it can't do; making it far harder to do.

Comment: Once the date of my budget is exceeded, I can't use it with my actuals
I have to take the next one
I put the H to show it's a hour
Normally, it's just an integer

Comment: Please do change it then (unless `'John` and `'Jhon`' are different people? If it's sample data, I'd suggest using more dissimilar names).

Comment: No I put the same name becuase it's the same person
Actuals represent the amout of time that a person works on a specific budget
If my whole budget is consumed, I start to use the next one

Comment: So `'John'` and `'Jhon'` aren't the same person? Then perhaps you could use less similar names please. `'Jhon'` looks like a typo of `'John'` and is therefore confusing people.

Comment: Yes they are sorry for the bad typing